# R client for a remote Ruby on Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, r

I will try to explain as clearly as possible my issue.

My company has a Ruby on Rails 3 environment. Guys in charge of the RoR environment spent a lot of time on it and made a great job at building a complex information system.

I am an R user, and I would like to take advantage of the Rails layer they developped.

Is there an easy way for a local R instance to connect to the remote Rails server and use its set of functions to retrieve data ? The development team has total control over the Rails environment/server and I can easily interact with them, but they do not know much about R.

I have been looking at RSRuby, Rserve (Rserve-Ruby-client), Resque, RinRuby... but to my limited understanding, it always seems to be Ruby being an R client.

For R using Ruby, apart from local call to the Ruby console (not Rails) such as
`x=system('ruby calc.rb', intern=TRUE)` . I could not find much.

Would stackoverflow community has some suggestion there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming R can invoke REST based services. Your rails team can expose the RAILS server functions using the REST interface. In Rails 3, it is easy to convert a HTML service to a REST(XML/JSON) service.

**Additional Notes based on user comment**

Let us assume that you have a `Users` controller with an `index` action to return a list of users in a HTML document.

```
class UsersController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with(@users)    
  end
end
```

To enable the `index` service to return the user list in XML/JSON format:

```
class UsersController

  respond_to :html, :xml, :json 

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with(@users)    
  end
end
```

Now

- `http://host/users.xml` returns a XML document
- `http://host/users.json` returns a JSON structure

The XML/JSON wire format is fixed by rails. You don't need to create a template for this. You should work with your rails team to get the XML/JSON document structure. A typical XML document might look like this:

**http://host/orders/1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
  <client-id type="integer">1</client-id>
  <created-at type="datetime">2011-04-03</created-at>
  <id type="integer">1</id>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2011-04-03</updated-at>
  ...
</order>
```

Comment: Could you explicit what is involve with "expose the RAILS server functions using the REST interface" ? I am more interested with some functions they have in Rails than the final rendered HTML page information.

Comment: An additional question: to my understanding, a html page is a template that will be feeded by some Rails functions embedded with this template. I am more interested with the raw data returned by the function within the template than the final html page. Does you solution allow that too ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know anything about R either, but it seems like you're likely to have the ability to load a remote URL and process XML, which means you could use activeresource to get data out of their system, and that's really all it takes.  A rails system isn't any different from any other web-based system at the application boundary (web server).  You could also get data back from Rails in JSON or any other format that's friendly to R if your Rails developers are willing to add those outputs (most of which you can get for free with one gem or another.)

Comment: Meeting you on the other side (I'm not familiar with Ruby), I can recommend the `RJSONIO` package as being great for processing and creating JSON.  It is speedy and provides a lot of functionality for how to process the JSON.  If JSON is a good interface with the Ruby side of things, then this may be a very useful intermediary.

Comment: yes, json is a good interface for ruby & RoR. Rails has baked-in JSON support.

Comment: Just to confirm, is it just a matter of enabling a gem to get this JSON feature? I am looking for a solution with no or extremely limited amount of work for the developpment team.

Comment: Yeah, it should just be a few lines of code for them using the JSON gem. If there's a highly nested structure it may take more effort, but not much.

Answer (score 0):

The advice from other blogs, e.g. http://www.r-bloggers.com/calling-ruby-perl-or-python-from-r/ , seems to be to go ahead and use system calls.   What you're hoping for is basically an interpreter, which is a big job (and usually doesn't work well :-( ).  I'd recommend you collect the basic system calls you'll be using regularly and put them into an R-function.  that way, you only  need to type
`> My.new.data <- tellRuby(data_to_get)`  and your "tellRuby"  function can call the dbase and return the desired data.

Comment: Carl, unfortunately, system calls are local and does not load the rails layer.